# How to open Facebook, twitter, linkedin & a url from tab bar items? swift

Tags: swift, webview, tabbar

Hello I have a tab bar on a contact us page with four social media items

I have searched the internet and found nothing on how to open Facebook, Instagram, linkedin and a website from tab bar items?

not bothered if its through the app (fb, twitter, linkedin) or if it opens the page up in safari...

Please advise thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `webView` to the controller and when you click on a `tabItem` on your `tabBar` load the page in your `viewWillAppear` function for your controller:

```
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://facebook.com")!))
```